# react native - convert array values to string compatible with SELECT IN Clause

Tags: javascript, postgresql, react-native, rest, axios

I am using the axios to call an API that handle Postgres data behind the scenes. This API has the following SQL Query

```
  const ingredients = await Recipe.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'category', 'title'],
    where: {
      id: {
        [Op.all]:literal(`SELECT recipe_id FROM ingredients WHERE NAME in ( ${ingredientsArr} )`)
      }
    }
  })
```

This WHERE clause with IN accept values as "X", "Y", "Z", but when I send the array, via axios, the value is like "X, Y, Z". How could I fix it to include this value at the IN clause correctly?

Axios API call:

```
    axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: "http://192.168.0.3:3333/report",
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: {},
        params: {
          title: "'" + ingredients + "'"
        }
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          setRecipes(res.data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('API CALL - /report - error: ', error);
        })
  },[ingredients])
```

I tried to split and slice and it have not worked.

Comment: You should do this in the api level, allowing client to send parts of the query would lead to sql injection, a simple string.split on the backend would convert it an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to share with all of you the answer I have found

```
let ingredientsArr = data.title
      ingredientsArr = JSON.stringify(ingredientsArr).split(',')
      ingredientsArr = JSON.stringify(ingredientsArr).replace(/[\[\]\\']/g, '').replace(/""/g, "'").toString().toLowerCase()
```

if anyone has a better solution, I still accept sugestions to solve it in a better way.

thanks in advance for the help.